# Search a Match and return value google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, match

I am trying to write a code that will look for a match (2 criteria) and will return a value.
Here is sample spreadsheet: [Sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SaGo-yA6YPP-Um68Sgm8H3yMyfqXclDQWl5_l4cxgs4/edit?usp=sharing)

What I want to achieve is:

1. Read Product and Stage data from the Result（段取）sheet
2. Find a match in DataBase sheet
3. Get the Time (cell next to stage) value and copy it to the Result sheet

DataBase is constant and it won't get change but the Result (product and stage) will change everyday.
Please think of it as of production process. In database you have written whole process and in the Result sheet you have current status of the production. I want to know how much time left to get final product and also I want to know time of every stage.

In the spreadsheet you have ExampleResult which is showing the result I want to achieve.

So I guess it has to be something which will look for a match first in Column (for a product) and then in a Row (for a stage). Original data has around 40 columns and 15000 rows...

Do you have any idea how it can be solved?

This is function I wrote so far but don't know how to move it further...

```
   function findmatch(){
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase(段取）");
        var srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow(), srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  var productlist = srcValues.map(function(r){return r[0]});
   var stage = srcValues.map(function(r){return r[2]});
  
  var arr1 = Array.of(productlist);
  var arr2 = Array.of(stage);
  
  var position = arr1.indexOf(productlist);
  if (position >-1){
      return arr2[position];
  }else {
   return 'N/A';
  } 
  
  Logger.log(srcValues)
}
```

and this:

```
    function match(){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ルーチンデータ（加工）");
  var srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow()-1, srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
 var lol = Array.of(srcValues);
var filtered = lol.filter(item => item);
  
  
  
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("結果（段取）");
  const dstValues = dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow()-1, dstSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var loldst = Array.of(dstValues);
  var filtered1 = loldst.filter(item => item);
  
  let map = {};
filtered.forEach(i => map[i] = false);
filtered1.forEach(i => map[i] === false && (map[i] = true));
let jsonArray = Object.keys(map).map(k => ({ name: k, matched: map[k] }));
  
  Logger.log(jsonArray);

}
```

I will be very grateful for any advice.
Regards,
Pimo

Comment: Can you describe at what point you are and what do you think it is going wrong? Also, can you describe better the issue you are facing?

Comment: @Kessy at this point I got another code of Javascript and it works well on small ranges but with the big it does not... The error I am receiving is that the data and range amount of column is defferent so it can't put data into result sheet. Also I am not sure if my code is correct. You can check the code in  the spreadsheet. I guess the problem may be solved with just regular formulas but I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to my problem.
Maybe it will be helpful for other as well

```
    function makeArray(srcValues){
  const maxSrcValues = srcValues.length;
  const srcAry = [];
  for(let i = 0; i< maxSrcValues; i++){
    let maxCol = srcValues[i].length;
    let rowAry = [];
    for(let j = 2; j<maxCol; j = j+2 ){
      if(srcValues[i][j]){
        let t = 0
        if(srcValues[i][j + 1]){
          t = parseFloat(srcValues[i][j + 1]);
        }
        rowAry.push({'stage': srcValues[i][j], 'time': t});
      }
    }
    srcAry.push({'product': srcValues[i][0], 'stages': rowAry});
  }
  return srcAry;
}

function getTime(product, stage, srcAry){
  const maxSrcAry = srcAry.length;
  for(let i= 0; i<maxSrcAry; i++ ){
    if(product == srcAry[i].product){
      let maxRow = srcAry[i].stages.length;
      for(let j=0; j<maxRow;j++){
        if(stage == srcAry[i].stages[j].stage){
          return parseFloat(srcAry[i].stages[j].time);
        }
      }  
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

function getDbProductByStages(product, stagesList,srcAry){
  if(stagesList === null){
    return false;
  }
  const maxSrcAry = srcAry.length;
  const firstKey = stagesList[0].stage;
  let stagesCnt = 0
  for(let i= 0; i<maxSrcAry; i++ ){
     if(product == srcAry[i].product){
       stagesCnt = srcAry[i].stages.length
       for(let j=0; j<stagesCnt;j++){
        if(firstKey == srcAry[i].stages[j].stage){
          if(isSameProduct(j, srcAry[i].stages, stagesList) === true){
            return srcAry[i].stages;
          }
        }
      }  
     }
  }
  return false;
}

function isSameProduct(idx, srcStages, destStages) {
  const maxDstStg = destStages.length - 1;
  const maxSrcStg = srcStages.length - idx;
  if(maxDstStg > maxSrcStg){
    return false;
  }
  for(let i = 0; i<maxDstStg; i++){
    if(destStages[i].stage != srcStages[i + idx].stage){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function getStageTime(firstStg, idx, stage, dbProduct){
  const maxCnt = dbProduct.length
  for(let i = 0; i < maxCnt; i++){
    if(firstStg == dbProduct[i].stage){
      if(dbProduct[i + idx] && dbProduct[i + idx].stage == stage){
        return dbProduct[i + idx].time;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

function doProcess() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // 1. Retrieve the source values from database sheet.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase(段取）");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow(), srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const srcAry = makeArray(srcValues);


  // 3. Retrieve the source values from Report sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Result（段取）");
  const dstValues = dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow() - 1, dstSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  // 4. Create an array for putting to Spreadsheet using the created object.
  const destAry = makeArray(dstValues);
  const maxDestAry = destAry.length;
  const result = [];
  for(let i= 0; i<maxDestAry; i++ ){
    let row = [];
    let rowPartial = [];
    row.push(destAry[i].product);
    let timeLeft = 0;
    let timeTmp = 0;
    let maxRow = destAry[i].stages.length;
    let dbProduct = getDbProductByStages(destAry[i].product, destAry[i].stages,srcAry);
    for(let j=0; j<maxRow;j++){
      rowPartial.push(destAry[i].stages[j].stage);
      if(dbProduct){
        timeTmp = getStageTime(destAry[i].stages[0].stage,j,destAry[i].stages[j].stage, dbProduct);
      }else{
        timeTmp = 0;
      }
      rowPartial.push(timeTmp);
      timeLeft = timeLeft + timeTmp;
    }
    row.push(timeLeft);
    for(let k=0;k<rowPartial.length;k++) {
      row.push(rowPartial[k]);
    }
    result.push(row);
  }
  const maxLength = result.length;
  let maxColl = 0;
  for(let i=0; i<maxLength;i++){
    if(maxColl < result[i].length){
      maxColl = result[i].length;
    }
  }
  for(let i=0; i<maxLength;i++){
    if(result[i].length < maxColl){
      let diff = maxColl - result[i].length;
      for(let j=0;j<diff;j++){
        result[i].push('');
      }
    }
  }
  const wynikSheet = ss.getSheetByName("wynik");
  wynikSheet.getRange(2,1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
```

Just run the doProcess function